# How to merge two dictionaries with the same keys without overwriting data?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've got an assignment where I need to take two csv's and turn the information within them into two dictionaries. The keys for both dictionaries are the same, I just need the information from one dictionary to be added into the keys instead of overwriting.
Example:

```
dictionary 1 - 'key1' : ['place1' , 'web address', 'phone number']

dictionary 2 - 'key1' : ['place2', 'different web address', 'different phone number']
```

I'd like the final dictionary to look something like this:

```
finalDictionary - 'key1' : [['place1' , 'web address', 'phone number'], ['place2', 'different web address', 'different phone number']]
```

Comment: Is this the only key you need to merge, or do you need to do this for all keys in the dictionaries?

Comment: I need to do this for all keys in both dictionaries

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a `defaultdict` and iterate through all the keys/values in the dicts to append all the values to the lists in the final dict:

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1' : ['place1' , 'web address', 'phone number']}
>>> dict2 = {'key1' : ['place2', 'different web address', 'different phone number']}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> final_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in (dict1, dict2):
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         final_dict[k].append(v)
... 
>>> dict(final_dict)
{'key1': [['place1', 'web address', 'phone number'], ['place2', 'different web address', 'different phone number']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dct_1 = {'key1' : ['place1' , 'web address', 'phone number']}
dct_2 = {'key1' : ['place2', 'different web address', 'different phone number']}

final_dct = {'key1':[dct['key1'] for dct in [dct_1, dct_2]]}
```

(or better)

```py
list_of_dct = [{'key1': [stuff]},
               {'key1': [more stuff]},
              ]
final_dct = {'key1':[dct['key1'] for dct in list_of_dct]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a list of the values from both dictionaries. You can use a dictionary comprehension to do this for all keys in the dictionaries.

```
finalDictionary = {key: [dictionary1[key], dictionary2[key]] for key in dictionary1}
```